# Visual Studio - How can I change the publisher name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, certificate, publish, publishing

After publishing a project, the program shows the `Publisher` name when installing. I need to change the `Publisher` name to something else.

I've tried changing the publisher name by going to Project > Properties > Publish Tab > and then Options, but this doesn't change anything.

I've also tried changing the certificate information by going to Project > Properties > Signing... but I'm a little stuck there too. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Application Install MessageBox]